# Monotouch: load XIB asynchronously

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xib, lifecycle

I would like to know what is the right manner for calling external XIB.

The method `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib` loads a XIB in a synchronous way but, in this manner, I can't override `ViewDidLoad` method.

In particular, my goal is to crete a custom `UIViewController` and load a XIB created in IB (this element is an item that is attached to a Superview). Then I would attach a tap action on the custom `UIView`. Without overriding `ViewDidLoad` method I'm not able to do it.

How can I find a good tutorial to understand all the different constructor which I can utilize into a `UIViewController`?

For example, Could you explain these ctors?

```
public MyCustomView (IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
    Initialize ();
}

[Export("initWithCoder:")]
public MyCustomView (NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
{
    Initialize ();
}

public MyCustomView () : base("MyCustomView", null)
{
    //---- this next line forces the loading of the xib file to be synchronous
    MonoTouch.Foundation.NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("MyCustomView", this, null);
    Initialize ();
}
```

Thank you very much. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you try to do seems to me like changing the behavior of the default event and action flow in CocoaTouch.

The thing is, that ViewDidLoad is exactly the place where you should do the initialization, not in the constructor itself, leave the NIB loading on the framework and just handle the ViewDidLoad as it is intended.

It really helps to read the apple's development documentation, this helped me a lot at the start: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html